# Given a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, prove a result involving conditional expectation by means of symmetry argument

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, martingales, symmetry

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq1}$ be an i.i.d. sequence with $\mathbb{E}\{|X_1|\}<\infty$. Let $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$ and $\mathcal{F}_{-n}=\sigma(S_n,S_{n+1},\ldots)$. Then, one can state that $$M_{-n}=\mathbb{E}\{X_1\mid \mathcal{F}_{-n}\}$$ is a **backwards martingale** and, by Law of Iterated Expectation, $\mathbb{E}\{M_{-n}\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_1\}$.

At this point, how can one prove that

> *by symmetry for $1\leq j\leq n$:*$$\mathbb{E}\{X_1\mid \mathcal{F}_{-n}\}=\mathbb{E}\{X_j \mid \mathcal{F}_{-n}\}\hspace{0.2cm} \text{ a.s.}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Define a permutation $f$ on $\mathbb N$ by $f(1)=j, f(j)=1$ and $f(k)=k$ for $k \notin \{1,j\}$. Let $Y_n=X_{f(n)}$. Then $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ are identically distributed. This implies that $\mathbb E (X_1|\mathcal F_{-n})=E (X_j|\mathcal F_{-n})$ because for any $E \in \mathcal F_{-n}$ we have $\mathbb EX_1 1_E=\mathbb EY_1 1_E=\mathbb EX_j 1_E$. [Note that $\mathcal F_{-n}$ does not change under the permutation $f$].

Comment: Starting from $\mathbb{E}X_1 1_{E}=\mathbb{E}Y_1 1_{E}=\mathbb{E}X_j 1_{E}$, how can you conclude $\mathbb{E}(X_1|\mathcal{F}_{-n})=\mathbb{E}(X_j|\mathcal{F}_{-n})$? Is it correct if I proceed this way? By law of total expect., $\mathbb{E}X_1 1_{E}=\mathbb{E}X_j 1_{E}$$\Leftrightarrow$$\mathbb{E}\{\mathbb{E}(X_1 1_E|\mathcal{F}_{-n})\}=\mathbb{E}\{\mathbb{E}(X_j 1_E|\mathcal{F}_{-n})\}$. By $\mathcal{F}_m$-measurab. of $E$, one has $\mathbb{E}\{1_E\mathbb{E}(X_1 |\mathcal{F}_{-n})\}=\mathbb{E}\{1_E\mathbb{E}(X_j |\mathcal{F}_{-n})\}$. And now? How to get to the final result? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: $E \in \mathcal F_{-n}$ is arbitraty. So we get the conlcusion from definition of conditional expectation.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Hello why is $E[X_11_E]=E[Y_11_E]$

Comment: @JhonDoe Becasue $Y_1=X_j$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks but I don't see why we can conclude that $E[X_11_E]=E[X_j1_E]$. Does it have anything to do with the set $E$. I know that $X_1$ and $X_j$ are independent with same distribution but it does not mean that $X_11_E$ should have the same distribution with $X_j1_E$.