# Question regarding the integral of random variables with same distribution.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X,Y$ are independent random variables with the same distribution then is it the case that for all measurable sets $A$, $E[X1_A]=E[Y1_A]$. I think it is true but I can't prove why. Any hints or suggestions? Also if the statement isn't true, what conditions can be imposed on the sets $A$ such that the equality holds.

Comment: @hgmath What can you say about the distributions of the random variables $X1_A$ and $Y1_A$? Are they the same?

Comment: So, $A$ is a subset of the probability space $\Omega$, right?

Comment: Yes A is a measurable subset of the probability space.

Comment: The distributions are definitely not the same, in general. For example, if $a < 0$ and $A = \{X\le b\}$, then you have$$P(X1_A\le a) = P(X\le\min\{a,b\})\quad\text{and}\quad P(Y1_A\le a) = P(X\le a)\cdot P(X\le b).$$

Comment: @amsmath Thanks. But if you have the time please look at the following link:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3691659/given-a-sequence-of-i-i-d-random-variables-prove-a-result-involving-conditiona?rq=1. In the answer provided, the poster says that $E[X_11_E]=E[Y_11_E]$. Could you explain why that is the case?

Comment: @JhonDoe sorry for my confusion in the first comment. I found this explanation that might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308816/conditional-expectation-of-iid-random-variables

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct. Just flip a coin twice. Then $\Omega = \{0,1\}\times\{0,1\}$, $P(s,t)=1/4$ for all $(s,t)\in\Omega$, $X(s,t) = s$, $Y(s,t) = t$. These are definitely i.i.d. Now, choose $A = \{(0,1)\}\subset\Omega$. We have
$$
E(X1_A) = P(X1_A=1) = P(X=1,s=0,t=1) = 0,
$$
but
$$
E(Y1_A) = P(Y1_A=1) = P(Y=1,s=0,t=1) = P(s=0,t=1) = \frac 14.
$$